# linq ordering grouped elements after groupby

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| FruitID | BasketID | FruitKind | HarvestTime |
|   23    |    2     |    6      |  1/13/2013  |
|   24    |    2     |    3      |  1/19/2013  |
|   25    |    5     |    4      |  1/21/2013  |
|   26    |    5     |    3      |  1/31/2013  |
|   27    |    5     |    6      |  2/3/2013   |
```

I want to query all the fruits that are in a certain list of `BasketID`, group the result by `BasketID`, and within each group, look at the last `HarvestTime` and return a list of all the `BasketIDs` that contain fruits with the `FruitKind` of 3 or 4 (FruitKind can have values between 1 and 8). For instance, if we pass in `BasketID` 2 and 5, `BasketID` 2 would make it back because its latest `FruitID` 24 has a `FruitKind` of 3 but `BasketID` 5 has `FruitID` 27 that's of kind 6.

This is where I'm stuck:

```
var TheQuery = (from a in MyDC.TableFruits
                where TheListOfBasketIDs.Contains(a.BasketID)
                group a by a.BasketID into g

                where .... "latest FruitID has FruitKind == to 3 || 4"

                select g.Key).ToList();
```

I need to ordery HarvestTime within each group so that I can test for the FruitKind of the latest Fruit. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then

```
var TheQuery = (from a in MyDC.TableFruits
                where TheListOfBasketIDs.Contains(a.BasketID)
                group a by a.BasketID into g
                let lastFruitKind = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.HarvestTime)
                                     .First().FruitKind
                where lastFruitKind == 3 ||
                      lastFruitKind == 4 
                select g.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: BTW, for now I'm workiing with Linq-to-SQL but the project will later be migrated to Linq-to-EF. Apart from the data context, is this query going to be affected?

Comment: @frenchie you mean if this could be executed in memory?

Comment: no, I mean still executed against the same database but with a different ORM (Linq-to-EF)